# How to stop input in SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I run the following code in SublimeREPL:

```
while(True):
    a = raw_input()
    print a
```

How do I stop input when this is running?  <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctlr+D</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> don't seem to work like they do in a terminal.

Comment: Try ctrl+space or ctrl+break

Answer (score 0):

You have to do <kbd>ctrl+break</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd> to break the infinite recursion and abort the program